# how to use adodc in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vb6

Another wall in my project. I always thought that connecting to a database using VB.net is also the same on how I did it on VB6. but its totally different in my opinion.

**in VB6**

[image]

we just need to right click>properties>find your file. viola connection established.
then just the fields to your textboxes.

whilst **in VB.Net**

[image]

I tried to add `ADODC` the property window in VB6, doesn't appear in here since *property* is the property window in the right side.

one thing, can I use something like this in VB.Net? because its really far simpler than the ones that I see now about OLEDB or MySQL connection string. Its really hard.

If there is no solution to this, maybe you know a site where connecting a DB in my app seems to be easy to understand. thank you.

**EDIT** I need MS Access for my database..

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?466658.

It's a pretty decent walk through of ADO.NET..